# Display product isbn & mpn under each product on category page/tpl

Tags: php, opencart

I am using opencart (1.5.6.4) and was wondering how to I display additional product data under each product, specifically i want to display the product isbn and mpn.

I am unsure on how to make the product isbn & mpn accessible within the products loop of my category.tpl

For example I want to be able to use something along the following lines to display the data:

```
echo $product['mpn'];
echo $product['isbn'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure this has been asked many times or solved somewhere on the internet, though google couldn't provide me with the correct results right now...

Here's only a short how-to:

Edit the `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` model and search for method `getProducts()` - in the SQL provide your properties to be selected as well. Find

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id, ...   AS special";
```

and change it to

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id, ...   AS special, p.isbn, p.mpn";
```

supposing these two properties are saved in the `product` table.

Edit the `catalog/controller/product/category.php` controller and search for the loop where the product data is populated and processed until it is finally being assigned to a final array of products, looks like:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb' => $image,
    // ...
);
```

Here you need to add your new properties:

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb' => $image,
    // ...,
    'isbn' => $result['isbn'],
    'mpn' => $result['mpn'],
);
```

Then in your template (`category.tpl`) you can easily display them in the `foreach` loop using the code in your question (make sure you adapt it for the correct HTML).